# Resize Windows OnScreen keyboard programmatically

Tags: windows

I wonder if it is possible to resize Windows OnScreen-keyboard in my program? What Windows methods to use for that?

Comment: What language?  Are you using .NET or are you limited to win32?

Answer (score 1):

simply use standard Win32 api.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question is old, but the given answer is really short. To add value to this topic I could not resist to add the following information:*

You could do something like this, the flag SWP_NOREPOSITION should make the iPosX and iPosY to be ignored by SetWindowPos. So only the width and height should change. I have not tested this code though.

```
HWND hWndOSK = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null); //Only the class is known, the window has no name
int iPosX=0;
int iPosY=0;
int iWidth=1000;
int iHeight=600;
if(hWndOSK != NULL)
{
    //Window is up
    if(!SetWindowPos(hWndOSK, HWND_TOPMOST, iPosX, iPosY, iWidth, iHeight, SWP_NOREPOSITION))
    {
        //Something went wrong do some error handling
    }
}
```

SetWindowPos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx

FindWindow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx